# Get all days before today

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I try to implement range picker from ant design in my react application. Also i use momentjs.

```js
 <RangePicker
      dateRender={current => {
        const allDays = moment(current).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

        const style = {};
        if (moment(todayDate).isAfter(allDays)) {
          style.border = "1px solid #1890ff";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
          style.background = "red";
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  </>,
```

Above i try to add styles for these days that are before today, but i get the result and for the next month (red bullets also are used for July), but my expectation is to add styles just for the days before today's day from June, so background red should  be used just for all months till 8 June. 

 How to solve this issue?
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-fire-xki5j?file=/index.js:288-762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the `.format()` and it works

```
const todayDate = moment();

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <RangePicker
      dateRender={current => {
        const style = {};
        if (moment(todayDate).isAfter(current)) {
          style.border = "1px solid #1890ff";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
          style.background = "red";
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Looks like you don't need to format dates for comparison.

Comment: Good Job, @Dmitro

Comment: @Dmitro Borchuk , could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377199/add-data-in-a-specific-proprety-of-object

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> @dmitro Alreday given answer, but you can also try this checkDate function  you just need to pass date in string formate

```
 let checkDate=function(allDates){
              let result=false;
              var dateParts = allDates.split("-");
              var dateObject = new Date(
                +dateParts[2],
                dateParts[1] - 1,
                +dateParts[0]
              );
              result=  new Date(dateObject) < new Date(new Date().toDateString())
              return result
            }
```

Comment: @Dmitro Borchuk, could you take a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574664/cant-download-a-file-in-reactjs