# Add data in a specific proprety of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this application:
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-smoke-n5f1e?file=/Person.js:123-1128 
The idea of the application is next:

1. Near each person is a select tag  with their genre.
2. Every person  should be able to assign it self to the specific `toy`, selecting an option.
   ex:  Carl can assign his self only to `toyType: "M"`, by selecting `M` from select, and after selecting i should get the next data:

```
    0: Object
    color: "red"
    toyType: "M"
    persons: Array[1]
              0: Object
              name: "Carl"
              age: 17
    1: Object
    color: "white"
    toyType: "F"
```

3. If another user clicks on `M` also his name and age should be added in `persons` array from above.
4. Disabled are options that not coresponds with the `type` proprety of person; EX: Lisa has `M` dissabled bicause her type is not `M` but `F`;
5. Each person can add it self to a specific toy just one time not twice.

```
    const Person = ({ person, k }) => {
      // console.log(person)
      const thisPerson = { name: person.name, age: person.age };
      function handleChange(value) {
        console.log(`selected ${value}`);
        const result = toys.map((i) => {
          if (value === i.toyType) {
            return {
              ...i,
              persons: toys.persons ? [...i.persons, thisPerson] : [thisPerson]
            };
          } else {
            return { ...i };
          }
        });
        console.log("result", result);
        return result;
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Select
            placeholder="select"
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {toys.map((i, k) => (
              <Option
                disabled={
                  i.toyType.toLocaleLowerCase() !== person.type.toLocaleLowerCase()
                }
                key={k}
                value={i.toyType}
              >
                {i.toyType}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
          <span>{person.name}</span>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default Person;
```

Here,

```
    if (value === i.toyType) {
            return {
              ...i,
              persons: toys.persons ? [...i.persons, thisPerson] : [thisPerson]
            };
          } else {
            return { ...i };
          }
```

...i try to implement the functionality where users can assign their self to a specific toy, but appaers an issue when another user wants to add his self to one toy where exist already a person, because the previous person dissapears and insted of him appears the last, but i need to have an array of persons.

Also i cant figure out how to prohibit users to asssign their selfs twice to the same toy.
**Question: Who knows how to solve the issues? Thanks**

Comment: It's not really clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  In the live demo each user can select one of two options, and that's it.  I don't see where you're storing any state information or what isn't working as expected.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @David, the idea of the application is: every person can be assign to one toy, which has the proprety `toyType`, if person `type` === `toyType` then paerson can assign his self to the to the toy. Now this functionality exists. But also every toy after assigning a persons could create additional proprety like: `persons` which is an array, where persons could be stored. Now i can add one person but if i add second it overrides previous from array, also i want to prohibit double assigning of the same person.

Comment: @David, tell me please if is clear. Thanks

Comment: @David, in `console.log("result", result);` i should get the result. Could you help?

Comment: Are you asking how to maintain state in React?  You're currently not *storing* that result anywhere, which is why it's a new result after every operation.  There's no state management in your application.  It sounds like you'd benefit the most from some tutorials on React and how to manage data in the component state (in this case likely using the `useState` hook in React).

Comment: @David,  could you show please?

Comment: @David, my question is not about the state, i want to know why i don't get data in the array (`persons`) , because if i want to add 2 persons in the same toy, the previous value from array dissapears. Could you help?