# Cliking on item overite another data

Tags: reactjs

I have this application, where users can leave their comments ant rate the specific car.

https://codesandbox.io/s/public-antd-modal-forked-hj6bh?file=/App.js

Now exists an issue when user fisrtly type a message and after that click on a start to rate, after cliking the star the the text from input dissapears, but id shouldn't emty the input, this should be only after clicking on `OK` button

```js
 const setRate = (category, rate) => {
    const newData = [...data];
    let index = newData.findIndex((c) => c.carCat === category);
    newData[index] = Object.assign(newData[index], { rate });

    setData(newData);
  };

  const setSingleComment = (category, comment) => {
    comments[category] = comment;
    setComments(comments);
  };

  function handleOk() {
    const newData = [...data];

    for (let category of Object.keys(comments)) {
      let index = newData.findIndex((c) => c.carCat === category);
      newData[index].comments.push(comments[category]);
    }

    setData(newData);
    setComments({});
    setVisible(false);
  }
```

Why it happens and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

updating state which is an object or array, should always return a new reference at the top level, otherwise react will not see a "change" in the object (it uses shallow check) and your component wont rerender.

```
  const setSingleComment = (category, comment) => {
    comments[category] = comment;
    setComments({ ...comments }); //a new object needs to be created here, otherwise react wont rerender.
  };
```

Stick to keeping state in a single place. In this case, at the top level. This would mean removing state from the `SetData` component, and simply passing down its values, and implementing the mutation method.

```
function SetData({ rate, singleComment, onRateChange, onSingleCommentChange }) {
  //only need to store state in a single place. In this case, at the app level
  const handleRateChange = (e) => {
    onRateChange(e);
  };

  function handleCommentChange(e) {
    const text = e.target.value;
    onSingleCommentChange(text);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Rate value={rate} onChange={handleRateChange} />
      <input
        value={singleComment ? singleComment : ""}
        onChange={handleCommentChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

See updated code here on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/public-antd-modal-forked-rqnh9?file=/App.js:2120-2127)

I hope I have realized your intentions.

Comment: nice anwer, will be helfull if will take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377199/add-data-in-a-specific-proprety-of-object   . You will help me very much if willl help and with the second question. Thanks

Comment: could you help me?